# How to find the velocity as a function of the elongation of a spring when it is hanging from a ceiling?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> A mass whose mass is $m$ is hanging vertically from a ceiling which is
>   tied to a spring which has a constant of $K$ is oscillating. Given
>   this condition find the velocity as a function of the elongation of
>   the spring.

The alternatives given are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\sqrt{\frac{K}{m}y^2+2gy}\\
2.&\sqrt{2gy-\frac{K}{m}y^2}\\
3.&\sqrt{\frac{K}{m}y^2-2gy}\\
4.&\sqrt{\frac{K}{m}y}\\
5.&\sqrt{2gy}\\
\end{array}$

How exactly should I find the velocity in this situation?. Could it be that since appears a square root that is related to the conservation of mechanical energy?

If this is the case it would be that:

$\frac{1}{2}ky^{2}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$

Therefore in this situation it would be:

$v=\sqrt{\frac{ky^{2}}{m}}$

But it doesn't appear in any of the alternatives. Exactly which part did I missunderstood. Upon inspecting this problem it doesn't explicitly mentions about the height from where the bob is hanging.

But I'm assuming that the intended elongation for the spring is $y$ hence it appears in the alternatives. Therefore, can someone help me here?.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for the Physics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that in all of options, when $y=0$ then $v=0$. So the extension of the spring is measured as a displacement from a point where the oscillating mass is stationary.

The second thing to note is that an expression for the energy of the system must contain three terms:

1. Kinetic energy which is $\frac 1 2 mv^2$.
2. Gravitational potential energy which is $-mgy$ (since $y$ is described as the elongation of the spring we can assume that $y$ increases in the downwards direction).
3. Potential energy stored in the spring, which is $\frac 1 2 Ky^2$ where $K$ is the spring constant and $y$ is measured as a displacement from the normal length of the spring (without the mass).

Adding these three terms together then conservation of energy gives us:

$\frac 1 2 mv^2 -mgy + \frac 1 2 Ky^2 = \text{constant}$

If we assume that the mass has been released when the spring is at its natural length, then $v=0$ when $y=0$, so

$\frac 1 2 mv^2 -mgy + \frac 1 2 Ky^2 = 0\\
\Rightarrow \frac 1 2 mv^2 = mgy - \frac 1 2 Ky^2 \\
\Rightarrow v^2 = 2gy -\frac K m y^2$